# Looking for auto API documentation wiki solution based on jsdoc

Tags: javascript, wiki, jsdoc, jsdoc3, jsdoc2md

We have big piece of JS code, documented with jsdoc syntax, which we would like to include in internal wiki in an automated manner.

Accordingly, i am looking for wiki solution that is able to auto generate pages with jsdoc from our code base.

Any idea ?

Comment: what format do you need the API docs in? markdown, html or some proprietary wiki format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSDoc's built-in feature to generate from source and apply your own template to it. Then from your WIKI you just link to the HTML pages it generated. You can automate this by using cron to run JSDoc's page generator each time and use it's templating functionality to make it look exactly like your wiki so when you link to it from your wiki, that it doesn't look different. This is what we do.

Answer (score 1):

1. First I recommend to *check* if the application code has a valid and complete jsdoc using `eslint`: [valid-jsdoc](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-jsdoc).
2. From a valid jsdoc can be generated :

   - Use the default template generator from [jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-default-template.html)
   - A simple tool [docdown](https://github.com/jdalton/docdown), which generates markdown
   - A more complex [Docdash](https://github.com/clenemt/docdash) with options like templates (lodash.com like), export configuration, etc. It generates a complete html.